# How to grant access to a folder which resides in a folder owned by another group

Tags: ssh, ftp, vps

**Situation:**
Group `A` requires access to `/path/to/dir/foo` to upload files through ssh or ftp, but the directory in question: `/path/to/dir/foo` is owned by group `B` *(if you'd like: `/path` is recursively owned by `B`)*, which should stay this way, for security reasons.

**My attempt for a solution:**
I create a symbolic link to `/home/A`, which `A` owns. Next, I grant permissions so `A` can access the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/dir/foo /home/A/foo
sudo chown -h A:A /home/A/foo
```

I figured that `/path/to/dir/foo` should at least be owned by a group that `A` is part of:

```
sudo addgroup C
sudo useradd -G C A
sudo chown -R B:C /path/to/dir/foo
sudo chmod -R 774 /path/to/dir/foo
```

After doing all that, I connected through an FTPS client as user `A` and changed directory to: `/home/A`. To my surprise the symlink is not visible, which is odd, because the proFTPd is set up to show symlinks.

I also tried connecting through SFTP to the same directory. This time the symlink was visible, but when I tried to access it, I got the following prompt:

> Cannot open remote file '/path/to/dir/foo'.
>
> Permission denied.
>   Error code: 3
>   Error message from server: Permission denied

That leaves me with little to no alternatives, since this was the easiest solution I could think of.

**Desperate attempt:**
I granted global permissions to `/path/to/dir/foo`, but I still couldn't access the symlink `foo` in `/home/A` as user `A`. Meaning: `ls -l /path/to/dir/foo` would print `-rwxrwxrwx`.

**Question:**
How do I create a symlink `/home/A/foo` which points to `/path/to/dir/foo`. Which `A` can access, despite `/path/to/dir/foo` being mostly owned by user:group `B` (`/path` is owned by `B`) ?

Comment: "/path/to/dir/foo is owned by group B which should stay this way, for security reasons." I understand your concerns but the easiest method would be to create a group C with user A and users from group B in it and open ./foo for group C. By far the easiest method.  
"To my surprise the symlink is not visible, which is odd" is explained by the "Error message from server: Permission denied" ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Isn't that just like what I tried? Except I didn't add user `B` to group `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directory is in an ext4 filesystem, you can [use ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs). Best explained by example; my user is `romano` and the other user is `default`.

As `romano`:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % mkdir -p a/b/c/d
[romano:~/tmp] % cd !$
cd a/b/c/d
[romano:~/tmp/a/b/c/d] % touch f1
[romano:~/tmp/a/b/c/d] % ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 0 nov 27 17:15 f1
```

Obviously I can write to directory `d`, it's mine... but from `default`:

```
default@pern:/home/romano/tmp/a/b/c/d$ touch f2
touch: cannot touch ‘f2’: Permission denied
```

Yep. No symbolic link will change the fact that `default` can't write there.

Now, as `romano`, I grant additional access to group `default`:

```
[romano:~/tmp/a/b/c/d] % setfacl -m g:default:rwx .
```

(read as: add `rwx` permission to group `default` to the current `.` directory)

...And now, as `default`:

```
default@pern:/home/romano/tmp/a/b/c/d$ touch f2
default@pern:/home/romano/tmp/a/b/c/d$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano  romano  0 nov 27 17:15 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 default default 0 nov 27 17:17 f2
```

ACL syntax is a bit convouted, but it's a quite powerful tool. See `man setfacl` and `man getfacl` for a full info and more examples.

In your case if you have `/path/to/dir/foo`  owned by A:A, and you want group B to have write access to `foo` you should:

1. add `+rx` permission to each of the directory leading to it for group B:

   ```
    setfacl -m g:B:r-x /path
    setfacl -m g:B:r-x /path/to
    setfacl -m g:B:r-x /path/to/dir
   ```
2. add `+rwx` permssion to group B to the directory:

   ```
    setfacl -m g:B:rwx /path7to7dir/foo
   ```

**Notice** however that seems we have a nasty bug around... See http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8527. I am not sure about the consequences --- the simple case above worked ok, but please check it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my end. I have even changed ownership to `default` or `A`, if you will. setfacl adds a + argument to `ls -l` which I am not familiar with, but other than that, it doesn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the tip Rmano gave at the end of his answer, even though the file access control list method didn't work.

It didn't work, because the full path, e.g. `/path/to/dir` requires at least *read+execute* permission: `sudo chmod -R g+rx /path`. This solved my issue, and I can now access the symbolic link in `A`'s home directory, and write to the containing files.