# How to set permisions for groups?

Tags: permissions, users

I have a problem with Ubuntu server version. I need to set access permissions for groups (and user in group) (Sorry for my English) eg.:

I have 3 group.

- developers
- managers
- administrators

And a following folder structure:

```
/data
 |-www
 |-swww
 |-pwww
```

I would like to set the following rules for it:

```
Folder | devs | managers | admins  
www    | RWX  | RWX      | RWX
swww   | -    | R        | RWX
pwww   | -    | -        | RWX
```

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/questions/553978/how-to-grant-access-to-a-folder-which-resides-in-a-folder-owned-by-another-group helps you. It's basically the same problem, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Access Control Lists (ACL). You can find about ACL [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs).

This should allow you to set permissions for multiple groups on individual folders.

You will be required to download acl: 
`sudo apt-get install acl`

and modify your fstab to enable acl file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, as every file/folder on an ext filesystem only offers to set permission for:

1. An owner user
2. An owner group
3. Everybody else

So, can't set file/folder permissions for more than one particular group.

Comment: True in traditional Unixes, not true with [ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs). See for example this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/553998/16395

Comment: Nice, I did not know about ACL. Looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs it says at the top: _Note: As of Ubuntu 14.04 coreutils 8.21~8.23 a 3+ years old bug makes ACL usage ineffective:_ http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8527 not sure how that will affect what the OP wants to do though, and this may well be the solution for him. :)

Comment: Yep, it is duly noted on my answer --- still, the simple cases seems to work for me. It's a matter of checking it... ;-)